# Search and Selection using Visualflows

Tags: visual-flows

The user would be presented with a screen into which they insert part of an Account Name.  The flow would look up the Account Name and present users with all accounts containing the search string.  User would select an Account. And proceed to the next step.

As per my understandings, we can assign the searched records to collection variables but we can not let the user display the collection from which user can make further selections.

Is it possible in Visualflows? Any suggestions..

**EDIT**

After the selection of Accounts are done, the user would be presented with a list of the Brands from the Brand object.  They would select one or more brands and click next much the same as happens when adding Opportunity Products. A loop would ask them if they wanted to add any more brands.  They would click Save and the flow would create Purchase Order records in the background containing the information collected during the flow and assigned to the Account they had selected.

Do I need to maintain 3 different flows working like the following:

1. From the Custom Button present at child object of Account, invoking a Flow to let the User edit the Account records already populated if any.
2. If the user wants to re-assign the Account - he may have to search those using visualforce select List.
3. After the selection of Account, user needs to select multiple brands (is it possible via visual-flows?)

Is this scenario going to use multiple visual-force pages? If so how should I let the user land on multiple pages and maintaining the selected values like brands?

Can't it be possible without using using Visualforce pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange attribute of apex:selectlist and use rerender for particular picklist. so it will reflect collection value in selectList.

Comment: I would appreciate if you code share some code snippet for that pls.